# Bash do not execute command on Ctrl+D

Tags: linux, bash

Typing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> exits bash shell as expected, but only when the command line is empty. When there's something typed on the command line, it gets executed instead as if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed. Is there a way to make it always exit?

Comment: I can not reproduce. What terminal are you using? However, I advice you to read the READLINE section of bash's man page. You can define shortcuts by customizing the .inputrc file of your home folder.

Comment: @dirdi "I can not reproduce. What terminal are you using?" putty. Hm... Interesting, I just tried a few online vms (just to rule out my environment) and I cannot reproduce there either. Now I wonder why would terminal matter in one case (empty line, exits) and not in the other (non-empty line, runs command)... That's very strange.

Comment: so what is the terminal you connect to where it does not work? same Linux version as the online ones? same shell version?

Comment: @Zina The terminal (emulator) I'm connecting with is putty (and I've tried with the bare-bones xterm as well). It will probably be hard to find the exact same versions, but locally I have machines with various bash versions 4.1, 4.2 and 4.4 and all behave like this (non-empty line + ctrl+d == execute typed command). Online I tested with bash 4.4 and it behaved differently (non-empty line + ctrl+d == nothing happens), so looks like it's my local setup somehow - perhaps the terminal emulator as dirdi suggested.

Comment: that was what I was suggesting, setup on on the receiving point. and I see you got a great answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the output of `stty -a` contains `eof = ^D`. This means the terminal sends EOF when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. Bash uses Readline and when there are no characters on the line and point is at the beginning of the line, Readline interprets it as the end of input, returns EOF and Bash exits.

In your case this functionality seems intact.

When the conditions are not met, a regular binding (if any) applies. Check the binding with

```
bind -p | grep -F '"\C-d'
```

With the default bindings the output is `"\C-d": delete-char`. And this:

```
bind -q accept-line
```

usually generates

```
accept-line can be invoked via "\C-j", "\C-m".
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get `^M` which means <kbd>Enter</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> which accepts the line. This is the mechanism. I expect you to learn that in your case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> triggers `accept-line` as well. This would explain the behavior in question.

Another possibility is your terminal emulator sends `^J` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and `stty` is set to send EOF upon `^J`. This would be very unusual but it could also replicate the behavior.

---

> Is there a way to make it always exit?

Yes. Now I assume your terminal emulator sends `^D` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and the unusual behavior you reported (executing the line) is only because of unusual binding in Readline.

In my Bash the default binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> is `unix-line-discard`, this clears the line. I can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> *and* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This will effectively work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> when the line is empty.

In Bash:

```
bind '"\C-d": "\C-u\C-d"'
```

Or (permanent solution) in your `~/.inputrc` (or `/etc/inputrc`):

```
"\C-d": "\C-u\C-d"
```

---

In case you want to change your unusual binding to the default one, invoke

```
bind '"\C-d": delete-char'
```

but this will affect just the shell you run it in. A permanent fix is to find where the undesired binding is defined and delete the binding. It may be

- in `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`  (a line like `"\C-d": accept-line`),
- or in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` or another file that gets sourced (a line like `bind '"\C-d": accept-line'`).

Comment: Ha! With `set -o vi`: `"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe`. With `set -o emacs`: `"\C-d": delete-char`. Great explanation and recommendations, thanks!